Fastify schema: return all validation errors
I'm trying to return all fields names which have not passed validation, because I need them to display the respective error messages under each input field on the frontend. But I haven't found a way to do this yet, I'm trying to use YUP too. I have already used abortEarly but it gives me the number of errors, without details, example: 2 errors found.... 3 errors found. But that's not what I need. How can I return errors in the format: {field1: message, field2: message}? Thanks in advance

You need to set allErrors: true

@ManuelSpigolon nope, seems like it's not what I was looking for, or at least I did not manage to make it work

It would work with AJV only - it would be cool to build a yup-compiler as I did for joi https://github.com/Eomm/joi-compiler

I found a solution. At the moment I'm using YUP validator with abortEarly = false, I'm parsing the error response setting a custom errorHandler in order to arrange the error response the way I'm looking for, collecting the errors by path (eg. email, password...)
schema: {
  body: yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email().required(),
    password: yup.string().required()
  })
}

server.setErrorHandler(function (error, request, reply) {
if(error.inner) {
    const errorDetails = {}
    for(const errorLine of error.inner) {
      if(!errorDetails[errorLine.path]) errorDetails[errorLine.path] = []
      errorDetails[errorLine.path].push(errorLine.errors[0])
    }
    reply.status(400).type('application/json').send({ 
      status: error.statusCode,
      error: 'Bad Request',
      message: 'Feedbacks.thereAreErrors',
      errorDetails
    });
  }
})

